# Recursively Expand Bootstrap 4 Sidebar To Previous State When Hitting Back In Browser

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

The below HTML, CSS, Bootstrap 4 code produces an accordion-style expandable/collapsible sidebar menu that looks like this:

[image: sidebar-accordion-dropdown-menu]

**What I'm trying to do**

Either via **Bootstrap 4** OR **jQuery** OR straight **Javascript**...

If I click the "Push Mowers" link and then click back, I want the sidebar to expand all parent nodes above showing the "Push Mowers" item again. This means the sidebar would need to expand (show): Gardening, Equipment and Lawn Mowers in-order to show the previously-clicked item "Push Mowers".

My first attempt to solve this is to add a URL Fragment to the last item clicked using Javascript:

```
<script>
  $('.list-group').on('click', '.list-group-item', function(){
      var clickedID = this.id;
      // alert(clickedID);
      window.location.hash = clickedID;
  });
</script>
```

Next, I'm not sure how to proceed. I started down this path but this looks horribly and inefficient especially since I'm using Bootstrap 4.

```
// probably a terrible idea
<script>
  if(window.location.hash) {
      var hash = window.location.hash.slice(1);
      var elem = document.getElementById(hash);
      var node = elem.hash.slice(1);
      var x = document.getElementById(node);
      x.classList.add('show');
      console.log(x);
      var pn = x.parentNode;
      console.log(pn.getAttribute('href'))
  } else {
    // Fragment doesn't exist
  }
</script>
```

**I'm really unclear how to recursively expand all parent categories above a given node.**

The Reproducible HTML, CSS, Bootstrap:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.1.0/css/all.css">

<style>
  .leve-0 {
    padding-left: 15px;
  }
  .level-1 {
    padding-left: 30px;
  }
  .level-2 {
    padding-left: 45px;
  }
  .level-3 {
    padding-left: 60px;
  }
</style>

<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="text-nowrap">
      <div id="sidebar">
        <div class="list-group panel">
          <a href="#node11" class="list-group-item level-0" data-parent="#sidebar" data-toggle="collapse"
             aria-expanded="true" id="gardening">Gardening <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i></a>
          <div class="collapse" id="node11">
            <a href="#node13" class="list-group-item level-1" data-parent="#node13" data-toggle="collapse"
            id="lawn-chemicals">Lawn Chemicals <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i></a>
            <div class="collapse" id="node13">
              <a href="gardening/lawn-chemicals/moss-control/" class="list-group-item level-2" data-parent="#node13"
              id="moss-control">Moss Control</a>
            </div>
            <a href="#node14" class="list-group-item level-1" data-parent="#node14" data-toggle="collapse"
            id="equipment">Equipment <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i></a>
            <div class="collapse" id="node14">

              <a href="#node15" class="list-group-item level-2" data-parent="#node15" data-toggle="collapse"
              id="lawn-mowers">Lawn Mowers <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i></a>
              <div class="collapse" id="node15">
                <a href="gardening/equipment/lawn-mowers/push-mowers/" class="list-group-item level-3" data-parent="#node15"
                id="push-mowers">Push Mowers</a>
                <a href="gardening/equipment/lawn-mowers/riding-mowers/" class="list-group-item level-3" data-parent="#node15"
                id="riding-mowers">Riding Mowers</a>
            </div>
              <a href="gardening/equipment/weed-wackers/" class="list-group-item level-2" data-parent="#node15"
              id="weed-wackers">Weed Wackers</a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need only to traverse DOM up and it is quite easy with jQuery:

```js
// just mocking history back
var historyHashArray = [
  "push-mowers",
  "equipment",
  "gardening",
  "moss-control",
];

var currentHistoryIndex = 0;

// get reverse order of $ elements
jQuery.fn.reverse = [].reverse;

function expandTree() {
  if (currentHistoryIndex < historyHashArray.length) {
    console.log(historyHashArray[currentHistoryIndex]);
    $('.collapse').removeClass('show'); // resets
    $('#' + historyHashArray[currentHistoryIndex])
      .parents('.collapse')
      .reverse()
      .collapse('show');
    currentHistoryIndex++;
  }
}

document.getElementById('back-btn').onclick = expandTree;
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.1.0/css/all.css">

<style>
  .leve-0 {
    padding-left: 15px;
  }
  .level-1 {
    padding-left: 30px;
  }
  .level-2 {
    padding-left: 45px;
  }
  .level-3 {
    padding-left: 60px;
  }
</style>

<button type="button" id="back-btn" class="mb-3">History Back</button>

<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="text-nowrap">
      <div id="sidebar">
        <div class="list-group panel">
          <a href="#node11" class="list-group-item level-0" data-toggle="collapse"
             aria-expanded="true" id="gardening">Gardening <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i></a>
          <div class="collapse" id="node11">
            <a href="#node13" class="list-group-item level-1" data-toggle="collapse"
            id="lawn-chemicals">Lawn Chemicals <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i></a>
            <div class="collapse" id="node13">
              <a href="gardening/lawn-chemicals/moss-control/" class="list-group-item level-2" id="moss-control">Moss Control</a>
            </div>
            <a href="#node14" class="list-group-item level-1" data-toggle="collapse" id="equipment">Equipment <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i></a>
            <div class="collapse" id="node14">

              <a href="/" class="list-group-item level-2" data-toggle="collapse" id="lawn-mowers">Lawn Mowers <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i></a>
              <div class="collapse" id="node15">
                <a href="/" class="list-group-item level-3" id="push-mowers">Push Mowers</a>
                <a href="/" class="list-group-item level-3" id="riding-mowers">Riding Mowers</a>
            </div>
              <a href="gardening/equipment/weed-wackers/" class="list-group-item level-2" id="weed-wackers">Weed Wackers</a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Update:
So with your click event, it should be something like

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  if (window.location.hash) {
    var id = window.location.hash; // luckily it already includes #
    $(id).parents('.collapse').collapse('show');
  }
});
```

Comment: Javascript newbie question: how to get the `historyHashArray` from the user's actual browsing session? I believed you defined it as a simple array for demonstration and demo purposes but in a real browsing session, how does one get this array? Thanks for your answer. I can guarantee you I'll be reviewing every piece bit by bit to understand it.

Comment: @jarad You already did this part. There is no history array. You just pick your id from url and put it into selector like in my example. You need just only this one line (reverse is not important) on document. ready..

Comment: Note that you should add hash into each href in your template. There is no reason for modifing it by js.. Or you can add hashes to href by js on page load too..

Comment: I'm sure this is my lack of understanding but one reason I didn't add hashes to hrefs in the templates is because the parent hrefs reference an ID, not an actual link. Your solution worked! It's clear I need to learn jQuery after asking this question. `$(id).parents('.collapse').collapse('show');` has some pretty powerful stuff going on in that single line. Thanks for your help.